# Nested foreach loops to add DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories and GetFiles to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, io, foreach

How would I iterate through each folder in a specific file path and then for each of those folders found iterate through each of their files?

```
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Path");

        foreach (DirectoryInfo folders in dir.GetDirectories())

        foreach (DirectoryInfo files in folders.GetFiles())
```

Comment: You have answered your question yourself!

Comment: I wanna go through each folder in a directory and then go through each file and extract its PDF metadata but I just couldn't figure out how to loop through each folders files.

Comment: But your code *is* iterating through all the files in your folders. Just replace the `;` with a code block which processes the files and exchange `DirectoryInfo` with `FileInfo` on the second foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your semicolon on the second `foreach` may be causing you grief, otherwise your code should work with slight modification.

```
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Path");
        foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles())
            { 
               // do stuff with file
            }
        }
```

Comment: GetFiles does not return DirectoryInfo

Answer (score 4):

If what you're after is a list of PDFs in a directory and it's children you can do this.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\output");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var fileInfo in files)
{
     // do whatever you need
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question doesn't exactly match the body of the question. I think what you want is to add all files in all subdirectories in one array.

One way of doing it is:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Path");

List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();

foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dir.GetDirectories())
    foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles())
    {
        files.Add(file);
    }

// files contains your list of files
```

Comment: I wanna go through each folder in a directory and then go through each file and extract its PDF metadata but I just couldn't figure out how to loop through each folders files.

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Path");

foreach (DirectoryInfo folders in dir.GetDirectories())
{
   foreach (FileInfo files in folders.GetFiles())
   {
     //Do something

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pfft.

```
foreach(var file in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Path")
                            .GetDirectories()
                            .SelectMany(x => x.GetFiles()))
    // linq baby
```

(btw, cudos on using DI and FI, two of the more useful yet ignored classes in the framework)