# Copy Files From Folders and SubFolders Automatically

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, dos, xcopy

How would I go about copying all *.mp3 files from all folders and subfolder to another folder? I would also want this to automatically overwrite any existing file with the same name without being prompted for comfirmation. I don't want to copy the folder structure. I just want to dump all the *.mp3 files into one folder.

Would I use something like `xcopy /y *.mp3 g:\MyOldFolder g:\MyNewFolder` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this batch file - make sure that `d:\target` exists already.

```
@echo off
for /r "c:\base\folder" %%a in (*.mp3) do copy /y "%%a" "d:\target"
```

For use at the cmd prompt reduce the `%%` in each spot to a single `%`

Comment: It took some time to copy 10,000 files, but it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to (1) get all .mp3 files in the source directory, store in an array, then (2) use move(array name, destination directory) instead of copy. A small C# app (Windows Application, so no window or Windows Console) could do this easily.

(1) [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591369/nested-foreach-loops-to-add-directoryinfo-getdirectories-and-getfiles-to-an-arra)

(2) File.Move(items, destination);

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following syntax for xcopy here:

```
Xcopy /S /I /E D:\data\documents E:\Newfolder\documents
```

For my own example and experience I used like: `Xcopy /S /I /E D:\music E:\music`.

If the Folder "Music" does not exist on `E:\` it will get created by the system.

Here is a link where you can learn more about: https://www.windows-commandline.com/xcopy-command-syntax-examples/