# copying specific types of files from a folder and its subfolders to a new folder - osx

Tags: macos

I've seen a way to do this in Windows in other posts like [Copy Files From Folders and SubFolders Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492376/copy-files-from-folders-and-subfolders-automatically) but I don't see one for doing it in osx?

Answer (score 0):

This is the command you need :

```
find folder1 folder2 \( -name "*.mp3" -o -name "*.pdf" \) -exec echo cp -v {} newfolder/ \;
```

This will show you the files to be copied. Remove the `echo` to do the real copy